# Getting a node.js application hosted on GitHub to run in Azure properly

Tags: node.js, azure, github

I'm trying to host a node.js application hosted on GitHub in Azure. I have made it down to the minimal example that still fails.

This is my `./server/index.js` file:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response){
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.end("Hello world!\n");
});

server.listen(80);
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:80/");
```

And this is my `package.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "testapp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "./server/index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node ./server/index.js",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

That is all files of my application. If I start it up with `npm start`on localhost it works fine, and I get the "Hello world!" response as expected.

Then I made a repo on `GitHub`, and pushed this application to `GitHub`, and have verified that both files are present there.

Then I created a `Web app` in Azure, and set it to deploy from this `GitHub` repo, and it seems that the build worked just fine. This is the output from `Generating Deployment Script`:

```
Using cached version of deployment script (command: 'azure -y --no-dot-  deployment -r "D:\home\site\repository" -o "D:\home\site\deployments\tools" --node --sitePath "D:\home\site\repository"').
```

And this is the output of `Running Deployment Command`:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling node.js deployment.
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Copying file: 'server\index.js'
Using start-up script server/index.js from package.json.
Generated web.config.
The package.json file does not specify node.js engine version constraints.
The node.js application will run with the default node.js version 4.2.3.
Selected npm version 3.5.1
npm WARN brewingdaytest@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN brewingdaytest@1.0.0 No repository field.
Finished successfully.
```

And Azure says delpoyment successful.

However, when I navigate to `appname.azurewebsites.net`, it responds with a `Status Code` of `500`, and no response data at all.

What is the puzzle part I'm missing here to get this to work as expected?

Comment: Is `80` the port that Azure is expecting to expose to the world?

Comment: I used `80` since that is the dafault http port, but I haven't set anything specifically. Where can I set this up? I can't find the settings for this inside the Azure Portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure makes the port for your app available at `process.env.PORT`, so you can do something like this:

```
process.env.PORT = process.env.PORT || 80;

server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

If the app is running on Azure, it'll use the port assigned by Azure. If it's running on localhost, it'll use 80 instead.

Comment: It's actually not a PORT as in TCP PORT, but a named pipe. Azure App Service uses **iisnode** to talk to your node processes over named pipes. See this: https://www.reddit.com/r/AZURE/comments/4iv0y4/deploy_socketio_app_on_azurewebservices/